# Master struct and dependencies

Tags: c, struct, include, global, circular-dependency

Perhaps I am asking the wrong question, but I am trying to work with the following design (include guards removed for brevity).

```
/* config.h */
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

struct config {
    struct foo foo;
    struct bar bar;
    ...
};

/* foo.h */
#include "config.h"
struct foo {
    ...
};

void foo_something(struct config *, ...);

/* bar.h */
#include "config.h"
struct bar {
    ...
};

void bar_something(struct config *, ...);

/* main.c */
int main(void)
{
    struct config config;
    /* initialize struct */
    foo_something(&config);
    bar_something(&config);
    print_config(&config);
}
```

This is the classic circular dependency problem. I can make it work by adding some forward declarations and moving `#include "config.h"` to the bottom of the files, but it doesn't feel right. All these structs used to be in the same file, but I wanted to break it up to improve modularity.

Is there a better way of doing this, or a better design pattern to avoid this problem?

FWIW, my target platform is a microcontroller, so I'm trying to avoid dynamic allocation and globals.

Answer (score 0):

In general forward declarations is a way to go. In your case, if `foo_something` and `bar_something` only needs the respective parts of `config`, it seems that

```
foo_something(&config.foo);
bar_something(&config.bar)
```

is much more straightforward. Otherwise, `struct foo` and `struct bar` are not independent enough to warrant separate header files.

That said, it is very hard to advice anything with so little details.

Comment: For the most part, each file tends to use only their respective struct. However, there are 1 or 2 places where they call a function that requires all of the structs.

Comment: I'd concentrate on how to redesign those 1 or 2 places. If there's no clear separation in functionality, there's no data separate. Sorry for being vague. With more details I'd probably advise better.